# Mockito.when method doesn't manage my service call

Tags: mockito, spring-mvc-test

i'm trying to make Unit Test testing a simple GET controller method apply MockMvc.perform method but when the controller receive a request the method Mockito.when seems to doesn't manage the method call of MenuService and the test throw an exception. The Exception says menuServiceMock is null
I'm working with Mockito MockMvc JUnit

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import edu.AG.LandingPageSanpietro.domain.Menu;
import edu.AG.LandingPageSanpietro.service.MenuService;

import java.util.Arrays;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.model;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
class MenuControllerTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
private MenuService menuServiceMock;


    @Test
    public void testHomeController1() throws Exception {
       Menu first=new Menu("titolo1","descrizione1","filename1");
       Menu second=new Menu("titolo2","descrizione2","filename2");

       Mockito.when(menuServiceMock.getMenus()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(first, second));

       mockMvc.perform(get("/manageMenu"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("manageMenu"))
            .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/src/main/resources/tamplates/manageMenu.html"))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("menus", hasSize(2)));

    }
```

My Controller

```
@GetMapping("/manageMenu")
public String chiamataGestisciMenu(Model model) {
     model.addAttribute("menus", menuService.getMenus());
    return "manageMenu";
}
```

The error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "edu.AG.LandingPageSanpietro.service.MenuService.getMenus()" because "this.menuServiceMock" is null
at edu.AG.LandingPageSanpietro.controller.MenuControllerTest.testHomeController1(MenuControllerTest.java:44)
```

I can't understand why when() method doesn't manage my menuServiceMock.getMenus() request for returning the specified list.

Answer (score 1):

Use the annotation `@Mock` from mockito instead of `@Autowired`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have not initialized MockMvc. Try Autowiring it or initialize it in @Before method:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ControllerToBeTested.class)
class MenuControllerTest {
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;
...
```

or you can even initialize it in @Before lik this:

```java
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new ControllerToBeTested()).build();
    }
```